# Order by n_ammounts of matching instances in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a program to query against my DB. I have to one_to_n tables **tbl_user_service** and **tbl_user_competens**

Given two arrays cheese are formatted into strings that can fit in an **IN** clause -> 'word','word_2' ...etc.

I would to query for all users with a matching service and order by the amount of matching competens they have.

My query as of now looks like this

```
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tbl_users.*  FROM tbl_users 
 INNER JOIN tbl_user_service
    ON tbl_users.region = '$region'
    AND tbl_user_service.fld_service IN ($services_in)
 INNER JOIN tbl_user_competens
    ORDER BY FIELD(tbl_user_competens, $competens_in)
  ";
```

The results I get returned to me are correct, what I am looking for is how to have them sorted based on the instances of matches can be found for a given user_id in the tbl_user_competens

**test_drive and wanted results**

```
Query_Data : 
Region : "Some_State"

Services : 'Webdevelopment', 'Some Service'
Competens : 'React JS', 'Native JS'

tbl_users:
  fld_user_id : 1    Region : "Some_State"
  fld_user_id : 2    Region : "Some_State"
  fld_user_id : 3    Region : "Some_State"

tbl_user_services :
  fld_user_id : 1  service : 'Webdevelopment'
  fld_user_id : 2  service : 'Webdevelopment'
  fld_user_id : 3  service : 'Webdevelopment'

tbl_user_competens :
  fld_user_id : 1  competens : 'React JS'
  fld_user_id : 1  competens : 'Native JS'
  fld_user_id : 2  competens :'React JS'
```

Result should be

User 1 since 2 matching competens
User 2 since 1 matching competens
User 3 since 0 matching competens

Comment: Can  you post some example data and what your expected result would look like?

Comment: You need a `count` and a `group by` in order to achieve that.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? What's the connection between the tables (I'm assuming a userId column)?

Comment: See edit of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining the components table, join to a table derived from it, selecting for each user id the number of components they have that match the list of components.
Also, instead of using `distinct` and joining the services table, use `exists` and a correlated subquery.
This will enable you to sort the results based on columns that aren't in the select clause.

```
SELECT u.fld_user_id, Region
FROM tbl_users As u
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT fld_user_id, COUNT(*) As number_of_component
    FROM tbl_user_competens
    WHERE components IN($competens_in)
    GROUP BY fld_user_id   
) As uc
    ON u.fld_user_id = uc.fld_user_id
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl_user_services As s
    WHERE s.fld_user_id = u.fld_user_id
    AND service IN($services_in)
)
ORDER BY number_of_component
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zohar, easy to understand and solved my problem just as needed. MWP of the day <3

Comment: Glad to help :-)